# Handlebars.js question background-color striped for {{#each}}

Tags: javascript, css, handlebars.js, each

Handlebars.js question

Making background color for {{#each}}

```
    <form action = "/ editday" method = "post">
    <div class = "row" style = "background-color: {{striped @index}}">
```

I use my helper striped.It`s Ok.

I wanted to change the background color via CSS:

```
.row.striped> div: nth-child (even) {
  background-color: # 000;
}
```

But nothing happened. Because the CSS is applied before the handlebars {{#each}} loop runs. CSS doesn't see the final document yet with a set of <div class = "row". Thus, for all row, background-color will be applied to all the same or none. nth-child (even), nth-child (odd).
Is there any other more convenient way to do striped?

Comment: I think creating 2 classes should also do the job (one for each color and apply class based on index is odd or even).

Comment: Why is "striped" within the curly brackets (`{{striped @index}}`) if you just want the literal string, "striped" in your output? The syntax `{{striped @index}}` would be for calling a Helper registered with the name "striped" - which you haven't mentioned.

Comment: Yes, I really didn’t tell  about my assistant’s code, sorry

Comment: striped: index => {
            if (index % 2 == 0) {
                return "WhiteSmoke";
              }
        }

Comment: Why are you mixing CSS classes with inline style attributes? This is complicating your task. What is defined in the `style` attribute is going to override what's defined in the class. Secondly, I don't think your issue has anything to do with _when_ the CSS is applied.

Comment: These are two different options. Either style and my helper "striped" or CSS. CSS cannot be used instead of a helper

Comment: Just update your Helper to return both variants. As in `return index % 2 ? 'black' : 'whitesmoke';` Alternatively, you could return classnames.

Comment: just CSS can't do this? Don`t helper.

Comment: CSS should be sufficient also. Just don't mix the two.

Comment: This is how it works:
`{{#each day.NameCategories}}
  <div class="row" style="background-color:{{striped @index}}">
    <div class="col s1"></div>
 ....
  </div>
{{/each}}`

My Helper:

`striped: index => {
            if (index % 2 == 0) {
                return "WhiteSmoke";
              }
        }`

If you remove: 
`style="background-color:{{striped @index}}"`

How to make the cols striped using only CSS and not using helper?


It doesn't work like that:

`<div class="row  striped" >`

CSS:
`.row.striped> div: nth-child (even) {
  background-color: # 000;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Why does your CSS selector target `.row.striped`? There is no "striped" class in your template. The only class you have is "row", as in `<div class="row">`.

"striped" is the name of your Handlebars helper, which you are using to generate a background-color applied with an inline-style attribute.

I think your problem is that your inline-style is overriding your CSS.

As you alluded to in our discussion in the comments, you can do this purely with CSS. Just eliminate the `style` attribute from your template and add the required CSS rules. Just make sure you are not targeting the missing "striped" class. The CSS would look something like:

```
.row {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.row:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Here is an example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/ac5kmzh2/).

For the sake of completeness, I will explain how you could use the Helper. You would remove the CSS rules and just apply the desired color based on the index. The helper would be:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('striped', function (index) {
     return (index % 2 === 0) ? "WhiteSmoke" : 'black';
});
```

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/v8hw9fxm/) for this as well.

Comment: Sorry. You have the same links for both fiddle.
If you do as you said with just CSS:
` .row {
  background color: white smoke;
}

.row: nth-child (even) {
  background color: black;
} `
Then all lines will be the same color.
And you use helher just like me inside style = "background-color:
Sorry, I don't see anything new.` row.striped` is an option if I write `<div class = "row striped">`. But this is not particularly important, since the essence does not change

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am using nodejs and express-handlebars. But this does not change the essence either.

Comment: @Illusion: Sorry for the incorrect links. I have fixed those now. The first uses CSS and no helper; the seconds users a helper and no CSS. Both result in alternating whitesmoke and black rows.

Comment: Thank you so much!
 It really works. I didn't get it because of an incorrectly positioned <form> element, as well as if there was a <hr> element. I did not give all the code, it is cumbersome, but now I think I should have placed all the code